# Poner cierta cantidad de ceros con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo un pequeño problema:

Tengo mi tabla en mi BD llamada `numeracion`, en la cual esta el campo `numeracion` en ella tengo los números de las boletas o facturas;

```
id_numercion      numeracion      id_estado
----------        ----------      ----------
1                 1               1
2                 2               1
3                 3               1
```

**Esto es la QUERY FORMADA CON LAS DIFERENTES TABLAS como ven hay un inicio y un final**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno esa es la tabla, en mi `JQuery` saco la numeración más alta, por ejemplo el `3` pero ese numero crece hasta `500`,

Lo que qiero es que al jalar el numero en este caso el `3` colocarlo en mi `div` como `003` y cuando llegue a `10` lo ponga como `010`

Este es mi ajax  en jQuery

```js
    function traer_numeracion(id_recibo) {
    //    console.log(id_recibo);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseurl + 'Venta/traer_numero',
            data: {id_recibo: id_recibo},
            cache: false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data)
            {
                var numero = data[0]['numeracion']
                if (numero == null || numero == "") {
                    //si el valor esta vacio me pone el valor por defecto que es 1
                    $('#numero_recibo').html("Nº " + data[0]['serie'] + '-' + data[0]['numero_inicio']);
                    $('#id_numeracion').val(data[0]['id_serie']);
                    $('#numeracion_data').val(data[0]['numero_inicio']);
                } else {
                    console.log(numero.length);
                    numero = parseInt(numero) + 1;
                    $('#numero_recibo').html("Nº " + data[0]['serie'] + '-' + numero);
                    $('#id_numeracion').val(data[0]['id_serie']);
                    $('#numeracion_data').val(numero);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Lo Que quiero:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo Que tengo hasta ahora :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la longitud seria siempre igual? es decir 4 digitos?

Comment: Acabo de subir la imagen de mi Query en la base de datos como vez hay dice el inicio y el fin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es: `("0000" + num).substr(-4,4)`. Los "0000" es con el string que desea rellenar, luego con el substr ubica las posiciones que desea que tenga el nuevo string.

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript#comment33639551_10073699

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Al momento de cargar el número, solo remplazarlo por un formato de 3 dígitos. La función **replace** queda perfecto para este caso.

```
function format4d(numero){
    return numero.text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
}
$('#numeracion_data').val(format4d(data[0]['numero_inicio']));
```

Sí es solo para mostrar en pantalla puedes formatear de está forma al momento de imprimir.

> Ahora sí siempre quieres tener esta forma te recomiendo que les des el
>   formato al momento de guardarlo y cambies sus tipos de datos a varchar
>   en tu base de datos para que se conserven.

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}

pad("3", 3);    // => "003"
pad("123", 3);  // => "123"
pad("1234", 3); // => "1234"

var test = "MR 2";
var parts = test.split(" ");
parts[1] = pad(parts[1], 3);
parts.join(" "); // => "MR 002"
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera sería trabajar con el método [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/slice)

```js
let num1 = 1;
let num2 = 10
let num3 = 100;
let num4 = 1000;

console.log( ('000' + num1).slice(-4) ); // "0001"
console.log( ('000' + num2).slice(-4) ); // "0010"
console.log( ('000' + num3).slice(-4) ); // "0100"
console.log( ('000' + num4).slice(-4) ); // "1000"
```

Comment: La opción de método slice es la mejor: simple y más elegante

Answer (score 1):

La función que buscas en un `pad`, hay una función que utilizo para ello:

```
function pad(num, largo, char) {
    char = char || '0';
    num = num + '';
    return num.length >= largo ? num : new Array(largo - num.length + 1).join(char) + num;
}

alert(pad(15, 4, '0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

La función ideal sería `padStart()`.

El único problema es que, **al menos por ahora**, no es compatible con todos los navegadores, entre ellos Internet Explorer. No obstante, como dice la misma documentación, es actualmente una [propuesta de ECMA Script](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-pad-start-end), la cual posiblemente no tarde mucho en llegar a los principales navegadores.

Es importante no perderla de vista, ya que, **en varias de las soluciones que existen hasta ahora**, **el rendimiento puede verse más o menos afectado** si usamos una función para rellenar ceros en bucles largos.

Puedes encontrar la información completa sobre ella en la [doc de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/padStart):

> El método `padStart()` rellena la cadena actual con una cadena dada
>   (repetida eventualmente) de modo que la cadena resultante alcance una
>   longitud dada. El relleno es aplicado desde el inicio (izquierda) de
>   la cadena actual.

---

Aquí un ejemplo de código de lo que sería un función `zerofill` handmade.

Llamando la función de este modo, por ejemplo: `zerofill(5,0)` te rellena con ceros a la izquierda hasta alcanzar un máximo de 5 caracteres.

Funciona no sólo con números, sino con cualquier otro carácter.

```js
/*
  * pos:  cantidad de  dígitos totales
  * fill:  caracter  de relleno
*/
function zerofill (pos,fill)
{
  var data=document.getElementById("datos").value;
  console.log(data.padStart(pos, fill));
}
```

```html
<input id="datos" type="text" value="" size="35" placeholder="Introduzca un valor y pulse rellenar">
<input type="button" value="Rellenar" onclick="zerofill(5,0);">
```